# Protect Directories with Login NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

(A "follow up" of [NodeJS Session Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295297/nodejs-session-authentication))

Using node, I'm using `app.get(...)` to `authenticate()` all my HTTP requests, which works very nicely, however, a work-around to this is the end-user simply inputs the URL into the browser.

so I'm sending a request to `app.get("/onePlayer",authenticate ... )` and if you're logged in, redirect to `/one-player/index.html`

So somebody could simply put `/one-player/index.html` into the browser and suddenly, they've gotten around the login check.

No big deal, I can just `app.get("/one-player/index.html" ... )`? Sure.. that works, but it means I would have to `app.get` EVERY FILE I would like login protected.

How can I login protect all my files, with the option to exclude specific files/http requests (example: login.html and createAccount.html obviously don't need an account to access)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get('/onePlayer', authenticate, function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('one-player/index.html', function(err, content) {
        res.render(content);
    });
});
```

Or something similar. You don't statically serve the HTML files, you simply serve them after checking.

PS: there is no error checking, and you may have to specify the charset of the file in the `readFile` options. This is **not** production code.